# Why does my code work in one environment, but not in another?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a kata on Codewars.  I'm supposed to write a function that returns the index of which number, is not like the others, in evenness(i.e. [1, 2, 4] should return 0).  I believe I have a solution, and it proves true when copy/pasting the code, and console.logging on freecodecamps live server, however, when i try to run the code where it is written, it only passes one test.  What is going wrong here?

I've tried testing with console.logs, and my solution holds.  I know I could just use filter to solve the problem, but i wan't to practice fundamentals.

```js
let odd = [];
let even = [];

function isEven(num) {
  if (num % 2 === 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function iqTest(numbers) {
  let nums = numbers.split(' ').map(function(item) {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
  })

  for (let i in nums) {
    if (isEven(nums[i])) {
      even.push(nums[i])
    } else {
      odd.push(nums[i])
    }
  }

  if (even.length > odd.length) {
    return nums.indexOf(odd[0]) + 1;
  } else {
    return nums.indexOf(even[0]) + 1;
  }
}
```

The function should accept a string of numbers, one of which will not be either even or odd, then return the index of that number + 1.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that there will be an exception? If not, what is the code supposed to return if all the numbers are the same type?

Comment: Yes, for the sake of this, it is guaranteed.

Comment: BTW, whenever you write `if (condition) return true; else return false;` you can almost always simplify it to just `return condition;`

Comment: Why are you adding 1? The example says that `[1, 2, 4]` should return `0`.

Comment: Bob is preparing to pass IQ test. The most frequent task in this test is to find out which one of the given numbers differs from the others. Bob observed that one number usually differs from the others in evenness. Help Bob — to check his answers, he needs a program that among the given numbers finds one that is different in evenness, and return a position of this number.

! Keep in mind that your task is to help Bob solve a real IQ test, which means indexes of the elements start from 1 (not 0)

Comment: Then why did you write **`[1, 2, 4]` should return 0**?

Comment: I suspect the reason you're failing is because your code is too slow. If there's just one different number, you don't need to partition the entire array. You can stop as soon as you find the exception.

Comment: Oh, IDK haha, guess i thought the details didn't pertain to the context of the question, I could see that being confusing tho.

Comment: Ok, so sometimes it's a string like this "1, 3, 4, 5", and sometimes its "2, 3, 4, 6, 8", so the odd one out, wont always be even.

Comment: Read the first 3 elements. If they're all even, search for the first odd number and return the index. If they're all odd, search for the first even number and return the index. If they're not all the same, one of them is the outlier.

Comment: @Adag89 y r u  doing indexOf(odd[0]) in the return? indexOf(0th element) will not give you result you expect

Comment: Or read the first 2 elements. Do the same as above if they're both even or both odd. If they're different, read element 3. Return the index of whichever of the first two are different from it.

Comment: @SudhakarRS Why won't that work? He's indexing a different array.

Comment: That was my first solution, but i couldn't think of a way to code it, but I have some ideas, I'll try.  Besides that, is my code logical/should work?

Comment: @Barmar sry. i didn't see it

Comment: I dont understand @SudhakarRS.  Since there is only one outlier, then it's corresponding array will always have one element, so if I return indexOf(odd[0]) +1, it always gives me the correct answer.

Comment: @Adag89 sry. I misunderstood sth

Comment: gotcha, i know its more verbose than need be, but i wanted to practice long hand if you will haha.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the in comments mentioned approach and search for at least one odd and one even and one additional item, at least three items and exit early if this combination is found.

No need to convert the values in advance, because the value get converted to number by using the remainder operator of `isEven` function.

For a faster return value store the index instead of the value and omit a later `indexOf` seach.

```js
function isEven(i) { return i % 2 === 0; }

function iqTest(numbers) {
    var even = [], odd = [], values = numbers.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        (isEven(values[i]) ? even : odd).push(i);
        if (even.length && odd.length && even.length + odd.length > 2)
            return (even.length < odd.length ? even : odd)[0] + 1;
    }
}

console.log(iqTest("1 2 4"));     // 1
console.log(iqTest("2 4 7 8 10")) // 3
console.log(iqTest("1 2 1 1"));   // 2
```

Comment: This works, but I'm losing the logic at the last 2 lines, could you maybe write this part in pseudocode?

Comment: I figured it out, I guess I didn't realize that even.length would return a boolean haha.